# Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.core.env.Profiles

Tags: java, spring-boot, kubernetes, config, classnotfoundexception

When I run the application locally the application is up and running but when i deploy the same application in the Kubernetes cluster i am getting the error

**Error**

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/core/env/Profiles
        at org.springframework.cloud.kubernetes.config.PropertySourceUtils.lambda$null$3(PropertySourceUtils.java:69)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.YamlProcessor.process(YamlProcessor.java:239)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.YamlProcessor.process(YamlProcessor.java:167)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.YamlProcessor.process(YamlProcessor.java:139)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.YamlPropertiesFactoryBean.createProperties(YamlPropertiesFactoryBean.java:135)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.YamlPropertiesFactoryBean.getObject(YamlPropertiesFactoryBean.java:115)
        at org.springframework.cloud.kubernetes.config.PropertySourceUtils.lambda$yamlParserGenerator$4(PropertySourceUtils.java:77)
        at java.util.function.Function.lambda$andThen$1(Function.java:88)
        at org.springframework.cloud.kubernetes.config.ConfigMapPropertySource.processAllEntries(ConfigMapPropertySource.java:149)
        at org.springframework.cloud.kubernetes.config.ConfigMapPropertySource.getData(ConfigMapPropertySource.java:100)
        at org.springframework.cloud.kubernetes.config.ConfigMapPropertySource.<init>(ConfigMapPropertySource.java:78)
        at org.springframework.cloud.kubernetes.config.ConfigMapPropertySourceLocator.getMapPropertySourceForSingleConfigMap(ConfigMapPropertySourceLocator.java:96)
        at org.springframework.cloud.kubernetes.config.ConfigMapPropertySourceLocator.lambda$locate$0(ConfigMapPropertySourceLocator.java:79)
        at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1259)
        at org.springframework.cloud.kubernetes.config.ConfigMapPropertySourceLocator.locate(ConfigMapPropertySourceLocator.java:78)
        at org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.config.PropertySourceBootstrapConfiguration.initialize(PropertySourceBootstrapConfiguration.java:94)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.applyInitializers(SpringApplication.java:628)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareContext(SpringApplication.java:364)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:305)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1242)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1230)
        at com.daimler.daivb.msl.MbappsSnapLocalSearchServiceApplication.main(MbappsSnapLocalSearchServiceApplication.java:30)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:50)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:51)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.core.env.Profiles
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:387)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:419)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader.loadClass(LaunchedURLClassLoader.java:93)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:352)
```

Dependencies I am using in the application are

1. spring-boot-starter-web - 2.0.8.RELEASE
2. gson                    - 2.3.1
3. json-lib                - 2.3
4. spring-cloud-starter-kubernetes-config -1.1.10.RELEASE
5. json                    - 20230227
6. xmlrpc-client           - 3.1.3
7. spring-security-oauth2-autoconfigure - 2.0.8.RELEASE
8. spring-security-config
9. spring-security-web
10. spring-cloud-starter-openfeign - 2.0.0.RELEASE
11. spring-cloud-starter-netflix-ribbon - 2.0.0.RELEASE
12. spring-boot-starter-actuator
13. commons-lang3           - 3.8.1
14. lombok
15. spring-cloud-starter-config - 2.0.3.RELEASE
16. micrometer-registry-prometheus - 1.2.2
17. micrometer-core - 1.2.2
18. spring-boot-starter-test
19. spring-cloud-dependencies - Finchley.SR3

Comment: It probably has to do with your Java version. Make sure that the java version that you use in  your computer when running this is same as the java version used in Kubernetes. Check your dockerfile to find which java version it uses. run `java --version` in your computer to find out your local java version. Both must match.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The version of Spring Cloud Kubernetes that you are using (1.1.10.RELEASE) requires Spring Boot 2.2.x. You are using 2.0.x. This older version of Spring Boot uses an older version of Spring Framework that does not contain the `org.springframework.core.env.Profiles` class. It was introduced in Spring Framework 5.1 and Spring Boot 2.0.x uses Spring Framework 5.0.x.

You should update your dependency versions to ensure that they're compatible. To make it easier to do so, I would recommend using the `spring-cloud-dependencies` bom as shown on its [project page](https://spring.io/projects/spring-cloud).

Comment: I am using spring-cloud-dependencies bom in the project.
<properties>
       <spring-cloud.version>Finchley.SR3</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>
<dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

Comment: I changed the Spring Cloud Kubernetes version to 1.0.0.RELEASE and application started in the Kubernetes cluster. Thank you